# Импорт таблицы в базу данных Mssql в Linux(Ubuntu)

Tags: sql-server

Никак не получается импортировать таблицу в формате xml/xlsx/csv в базу данных mssql. ОС на компьютере Ubuntu, сам сервер в Docker, менеджер использую DBEAVER. Использовал следующие варианты - OPENROWSET, OPENDATASOURCE, BULK INSERT. Ни один не срабатывает. Выдают каждый свои ошибки. Есть еще какие-нибудь методы? Или может я неправильно что-то делаю.
Например, при использовании BULK INSERT выдает ошибку, что файл не существует или у вас нет прав доступа к файлу. Код следующий
 `BULK INSERT TempRate
   FROM '/home/dan/Marathon/Temp.csv'
    WITH
    (
    FIRSTROW = 2,
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
    ERRORFILE = '/home/dan/ErrorRows.csv',
    TABLOCK
    )`

Comment: Cтоит остановиться на каком то конкретном методе, внимательно посмотреть на сообщения об ошибках и постараться их исправить. может там какая нибудь особенность в данных, которая не учтена в настройках загрузки. А ответить на вопрос в котором нет ни примера загружаемых данных, ни сообщений об ошибках сможет только гадалка

Comment: Ошибка выводится следующая: `SQL Error [4860] [S0001]: Cannot bulk load. The file "/home/dan/Marathon/Temp.csv" does not exist or you don't have file access rights.`

Comment: MS SQL у вас установлен на той же машине на которой лежит файл Temp.csv и под каким пользователем ОС работает MS SQL, может ему просо не хватает прав зайти в папку /home/dan ?

Comment: Есть сомнения в том, что необходимо вначале скопировать файл в докер, а уже оттуда импортировать. Но пока не получается.

Comment: Главное что бы файл был там же, где сам SQL SERVER, а не где клиент, который запускает оператор загрузки. Если сервер в докере, то файл должен быть там же.

Comment: Решил проблему. В терминале необходимо перейти к папке, содержащей файл и оттуда скопировать в контейнер командой `dan@dan-desktop:~/Marathon$ sudo docker cp Transactions.csv mssql-server-linux:/root`,  затем соответственно в скрипте мы указываем источник `/root/Transactions.csv`. После этого `BULK INSERT` работает правильно.